# Problems using pandas read sql with a connection using cx_Oracle 6.0b2

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, cx-oracle

When using cx_Oracle 5.3 I did not have this issue, but for a particularly large query that I am trying to run using:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('Username/Password@host/dbname')

pd.read_sql(Query,connection)

I get the following value error:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-916f315e0bf6> in <module>()
----> 1 OracleEx = pd.read_sql(x,connection)
      2 OracleEx.head()

C:\Users\kevinb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    497             sql, index_col=index_col, params=params,
    498             coerce_float=coerce_float, parse_dates=parse_dates,
--> 499             chunksize=chunksize)
    500 
    501     try:

C:\Users\kevinb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize)
   1606                                         parse_dates=parse_dates)
   1607         else:
-> 1608             data = self._fetchall_as_list(cursor)
   1609             cursor.close()
   1610 

C:\Users\kevinb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in _fetchall_as_list(self, cur)
   1615 
   1616     def _fetchall_as_list(self, cur):
-> 1617         result = cur.fetchall()
   1618         if not isinstance(result, list):
   1619             result = list(result)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '8.9'
```

Setting up my own cursor and using cur.fetchall() I get a similar result:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-d32c0f219cdf> in <module>()
----> 1 y=x.fetchall()
      2 pd.DataFrame(y)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7.3'
```

The values '8.9' and '7.3' change with every run.

Any ideas on why I am getting these value errors? 
pd.read_sql and using cur.fetchall() have worked for some queries, but not the particular one I am using which has worked in previous versions of cx_Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the release candidate instead of beta 2. There was an issue when retrieving certain numeric expressions.

`python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade --pre`

Comment: Thanks for the response Anthony. I just tried running the pip install command pasted above and I got the following response:       Requirement already up-to-date: cx_Oracle in c:\users\kevinb\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages

Comment: Admittedly I'm not very familiar with the pip upgrade commands, but is there another simple means of getting the release candidate?  

It took quite some time to get all the requirements in the correct place to get the beta 2 installed

Comment: You can go to PyPI and download the wheel directly. You can also uninstall and then re-install using the pip command noted above, and then confirm you have cx_Oracle 6.0rc1.